# WinUSB architecture docs confusion over winusb.sys instances

Tags: drivers, winusb

I'm trying to understand the "WinUSB Architecture and Modules" doc at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

In the diagram I see multiple instances of winusb.sys (numbered 1 to 3), supporting multiple user-mode "Device Interfaces" A through C. The narrative says things like "the following figure shows a USB driver stack that contains several instances of Winusb.sys".

Yet the narrative also says "There is exactly one loaded instance of Winusb.sys." Huh? How does that reconcile with the diagram and preceding narrative that show multiple instances? And I'm not seeing how the remainder of that paragraph, about PDOs, relates to the puzzling comment about exactly one instance of Winusb.sys.

Clues anyone?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a misleading architecture diagram. There is only one instance of `winusb.sys` loaded, but what happens is each device that enumerates will create a Device Object that is used by that driver (in this case, there would be three objects managed by the WinUSB driver). I believe what the diagram is showing is what the possible driver stacks would look like for each device instance, and in reality the layer for the `winusb.sys` driver should be a block at the top that the each of the user mode device instances are interfacing with.

Comment: This certainly appeals to me. However, I'd like to know for sure;  the narrative is so persistent in discussing the multiple winusb.sys instances as separate instances.  Do you have any reference that shows a stack configured like you describe? I guess the salient feature would be a single winusb.sys, with multiple PDO's associated to it, talking to multiple user-mode device interfaces.

Comment: This is a better look at what stack looks like - it's not showing what the PDOs look like: [USB Driver Stack Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Read this [WDM Concepts for WDF Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a description on how the stack is built. The key here is that each driver (xxxxxxx.sys file) is building the stack of `DEVICE_OBJECT` used between the drivers.